# keyNotFound Swift Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, data-class

Model Class

```
public struct Products : Codable {
    let data: [ProductData]
    let error: Bool
    let message: String
}

public struct ProductData : Codable {
    let id, category, subCategory, name, status: String
}
```

ViewModel Class :

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

final class GetProductsViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var products : [ProductData] = []
    
    func productRequest() {
        
        let productsurl = "https://auroraa.site/suresh-packers/admin/api/get-products.php"
        
        AF.request(productsurl, method: .post,
                   parameters: ["type": "get_products","sub_category": "2"],
                   encoding: URLEncoding.default,
                   headers: nil,
                   interceptor: nil).response { responce in
            
            switch responce.result {
                
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Products.self, from: data!)
                    print("Product Names : ",jsonData)
                    self.products = jsonData.data
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app .. Api call return the error statement of

"keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "subCategory", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "subCategory", intValue: nil) ("subCategory").", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: If the key is not in every dictionary make it optional `let subCategory: String?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API dose not send "subCategory"
Maybe "SubCategory" is receiving.
You can use CodingKey like this

```
public struct ProductData : Codable {
    let id, category, subCategory, name, status: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        ...

        case subCategory        = "SubCategory"
        case category           = "Category"
        ...
    }

}
```